# Default color highlight while pressing button

Tags: java, mouseevent, jbutton, mouselistener

I'm making a using a mouse listener on a button to detect whether or not the mouse entered the button.

The default coloring is not the color I'm supposed to be using, a bluish color.

When entered the button changes colors in the borders and I used

```
button.setBorderPainted(false);
```

to take it off.

I also changed isFocusable to false to avoid the highlighting of the text field. However, I can't seem to find a method that turns off the default highlighting when

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
```

is called.

Comment: Things like contentAreaFilled or setRolloverEnabled

Comment: I'd also recommend using the ButtonModel instead of MouseListener

Comment: Thanks but they didn't work. ButtonModel appears to be what I really needed. Thanks!

Comment: What look and feel are you using? Consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem